# Custom validation with Antd and redux-form-antd

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd

I am using `redux-form-antd` and I am getting somehow confused regarding validation. For an `Input` I am using the following:

```
import { Field } from "redux-form";
import { TextField } from 'redux-form-antd';

// validation
const validateAcronym = {
    validate: v => (v ? '' : 'Error')
};

// form layout
const formItemLayout = {
    labelCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 8 },
    },
    wrapperCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 16 },
    },
};

// antd field
<Field
    {...formItemLayout}
    {...validateAcronym}
    label="Acronym" name="acronym"
    component={TextField}
    placeholder="The Acronym of this Token"
/>
```

What I don't like is the Error message of my Field. I would like to use a lambda so that I can pass a custom error message on each field but if I transform the validate into a Lambda, I get errors on React. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use "redux-form-antd": "3.0.3" and this way works for me.

validations.js

```
export const required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required');
```

Form.js

```
import { required } from './validations';

<Field
    label="Acronym" name="acronym"
    component={TextField}
    validate={[required]}
    placeholder="The Acronym of this Token"
 />
```

I hope this help, Cheers